# no option to render with a radeon rx 550

Tags: rendering

I've been scouring the net to find out if I can use my rx 550 to render my projects in blender but in user preferences there seems to be no option to do so it just shows no compatible gpus found for cycle. And the forums I've checked so far are just giving answers in gray. I do not know for certain if there is a plugin or whatever for this as of now .I've tried the amd pro renderer addon but it just crashes the whole software whenever I try to render. Hence I am in desperate need of solid answers and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#gpu-rendering